# Is "equal to none" a fixed phrase?

Tags: phrases, idioms

I encountered this as a phrase in

> Trent Hawkins is a skilled pilot and war veteran, whose piloting skill are **equal to none**

and it seems a bit strange. Is this an actual phrase or has the author of this sentence botched this up?

Comment: As you suspect, it's a mistake: a confusion of "second to none" and "equalled by none". And singular *skill* requires the singular verb *is*.

Comment: Yes, I am temped to read "equal to none" as meaning "not very good", a bit like "Is there no start to this man's talent?" I'm sure that's not what the writer meant but still...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An idiomatic way to say this is with the phrase "[second to none](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/second_to_none)"

> Trent Hawkins is a skilled pilot and war veteran, whose piloting skill
>   is second to none.

It means that nobody is better than Trent.

Comment: You could also say that his skills are *unequalled*.